# Error "Dimension too large" (\@tempdima) when using HTML color 097054 with beamer's \setbeamercovered{transparent} option

Tags: beamer, color, transparency

The code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{\setbeamercovered{transparent}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \onslide<2>{\textcolor[HTML]{097054}{foo}}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

results in the error `! Dimension too large`: `\@tempdima`.  Is there a known/simple fix for this?

Comment: If you define `\definecolor{somecolor}{HTML}{097054}` and then use `\onslide<2>{\textcolor{somecolor}{foo}}` it works.

Comment: It's a good idea to define colors, as shown in percusse's comment, in the preamble, so that one can be consistent in their usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding the color definition

`\definecolor{somecolor}{HTML}{097054}`

to the preamble and later using it via

`\onslide<2>{\textcolor{somecolor}{foo}}`

solves the problem.